# Difference between dates in PySpark SQL

Tags: sql-server, pyspark, bigdata

So I need to compute the difference between two dates. I know that PySpark SQL does support `DATEDIFF` but only for day. I made a function that computes difference, but I just have no output. Code looks like that:

```
     ...
logRowsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("taxiTable")
#first way
spark.registerFunction("test", lambda x,y: ((dt.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - dt.strptime(y, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')).days * 24 * 60) + ((dt.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - dt.strptime(y, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')).seconds/60))
#second
spark.registerFunction("test", lambda x,y: countTime(x,y))
#third
diff = udf(countTime)
#trying to call that function that way
listIpsDF = spark.sql('SELECT diff(pickup,dropoff) AS TIME FROM taxiTable')
```

Function:

```
def countTime(time1, time2):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    d1 = dt.strptime(time1, fmt)
    d2 = dt.strptime(time2, fmt)
    diff = d2 -d1
    diff_minutes = (diff.days * 24 * 60) + (diff.seconds/60)
    return str(diff_minutes)
```

It just doesn't work. Can you help me?

An example:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|             pickup|            dropoff|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2018-01-01 00:21:05|2018-01-01 00:24:23|
|2018-01-01 00:44:55|2018-01-01 01:03:05|
|                  ...                  |
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Expected output (in minutes):

```
+-------------------+
|    datediff       |
+-------------------+
|        3.3        |
| 18.166666666666668|
|        ...        |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Please add an example of your input and your expected output.

Comment: @cronoik done, I have added some examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I'm not sure where you error is because some of your sample code doesn't makes sense (for example you register a function called 'test' but you use the function diff in your sql statement which is not registred -> that should lead to an error message). Anyway please find an working example of your code below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from datetime import datetime as dt

l = [('2018-01-01 00:21:05','2018-01-01 00:24:23')
,('2018-01-01 00:44:55', '2018-01-01 01:03:05')
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(l,['begin','end'])
df.registerTempTable('test')

def countTime(time1, time2):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    d1 = dt.strptime(time1, fmt)
    d2 = dt.strptime(time2, fmt)
    diff = d2 - d1
    diff_minutes = (diff.days * 24 * 60) + (diff.seconds/60)
    return str(diff_minutes)

diff = udf(countTime)
sqlContext.registerFunction("diffSQL", lambda x, y: countTime(x,y))

print('column expression udf works')
df.withColumn('bla', diff(df.begin,df.end)).show()
print('sql udf works')
spark.sql('select diffSQL(begin,end) from test').show()
```

Output of the example:

```
column expression udf works
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+ 
|              begin|                end|               bla| 
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+ 
|2018-01-01 00:21:05|2018-01-01 00:24:23|               3.3| 
|2018-01-01 00:44:55|2018-01-01 01:03:05|18.166666666666668| 
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+ 
sql udf works 
+-------------------+ 
|diffSQL(begin, end)| 
+-------------------+ 
|                3.3| 
| 18.166666666666668|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! I forget "SQLContext" import and "sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)" line. Thanks you again :D